# Neo4j - Does relationship direction affect cypher performance?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Something I've always been curious about.

(Assuming you could magically flip the directions of relationships in neo4j)

Which would be faster?

```
START a=node(345)
MATCH (a)<-[:foo]-(b)<-[:bar]-(c)
RETURN c
```

or

```
START a=node(345)
MATCH (a)-[:foo]->(b)-[:bar]->(c)
RETURN c
```

Or does it not matter, as under the hood, you can traverse in either direction?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer in the javadocs (http://api.neo4j.org/current/org/neo4j/graphdb/Relationship.html)

> Even though all relationships have a direction they are equally well traversed in both directions so there's no need to create duplicate relationships in the opposite direction (with regard to traversal or performance).

That answers that.